# What is meant by "raconter des salades"?

Tags: expressions, sens

I can't get what is meant here:

> Raconter des salades

Literally, “to tell some salad”. I don't understand the English translation “to tell tall tales” either.

Comment: You'll find that a *tall tale* is something more specific than a mere *tale*, but it doesn't make any difference here when explaining the meaning of *raconter des salades*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Raconter des salades* means *to tell lies/incredible stories*. Nothing to do with food, it's a figure of speech.

L'emploi de *salade* pour un mélange hétérogène au sens figuré est apparu au Moyen-Âge, employé semble-t-il pour la première fois dans le livre d'[Antoine de la Sale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_de_la_sale) *[La salade](http://www.biblisem.net/etudes/parisprs.htm)* (1441), qui était une compilation d'histoires.

Ensuite en 1856 on trouve l'emploi de « salade » pour parler d'une réunion de choses confusément assemblées et on aboutit à la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle à *salade* — le plus souvent au pluriel — pour « histoires mensongères ». Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) dit 1901 ([Aristide Bruant](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristide_Bruant)) sans toutefois citer d'exemple.

---

*Tell tall tales* means *tell lies* (although this should really be explained on EL&U)!

*Salade* started to be used in  figurative sense in the Middle-Ages, it is said to have been used for the first time by [Antoine de la Sale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_de_la_sale) in his book *[La salade](http://www.biblisem.net/etudes/parisprs.htm)* (1441), which was a compilation of stories.

It started to be used with the meaning of “tell lies/incredible stories” at the end of the XIX<sup>th</sup> century.  Attested in the *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* to have been used in that sense in 1901 by [Aristide Bruant](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristide_Bruant) but no example is given.

Answer (score 0):

For the English meaning: a “tale” is nearly synonymous with “story”, whereas “tall tale” implies that there is more falsified in the story. It is used in both good connotations and bad connotations: “My grandfather told me tall tales of his youth” (which implies enjoyable but perhaps not 100% factual stories), or “She said that she was late because her car broke down, but that's just a tall tale” (which is synonymous with “lie” in this case).

Sometimes “tale” means a completely fictitious story, like a fairy tale, whereas “tall tale” means a story based on fact but not entirely factual.